# Derivative of loglikehood like matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a function
$$
f(C)
= \text{trace}(X X^T C - \log(C)), 
$$
Here $X$ is $n \times k$ matrix, $C$ is strictly positive definite symmetric matrix parametrized as follows
$$
C
= (D + U F U^T)^{-1}.
$$
$D$ is positive diagonal, $F$ is a symmetric positive definite $p \times p$ matrix, where $p < n$.
$U$ is a $n \times p$ matrix of full rank.

How can I find a derivative of $f$ with respect to $F$?
Note that derivative of $f$ with respect to $C$ is:
$$
X X^T - C^{-1}.
$$
But I have problems to proceed. I expect to get and the end a $p \times p$ matrix, something like 
$$
U^T (\ldots) U.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Most of these Identities come from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Using $g$ instead of $f$, and assuming your derivative is correct:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g(C(F))}{\partial F_{ij}} = &\; tr\left(\frac{\partial g(C)}{\partial C} \cdot \frac{\partial C}{\partial F_{ij}} \right) \\
= &\;tr\left(\left(XX^T-C^{-1}\right) \frac{\partial C}{\partial F_{ij}} \right)
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial F_{ij}} = &\; \frac{\partial}{\partial F_{ij}}\left(D+UFU^T\right)^{-1}\\
= &\;-(D+UFU^T)^{-1}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial F_{ij}} (D+UFU^T)\right](D+UFU^T)^{-1}\\
= &\;-(D+UFU^T)^{-1}UE_{ij}U^T(D+UFU^T)^{-1} \\
= &\;-CUE_{ij}U^TC
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g(C(F))}{\partial F_{ij}} = &\; tr\left(\left(XX^T-C^{-1}\right) (-CUE_{ij}U^TC) \right)\\
= &\; -tr(U^TC(XX^T-C^{-1})CUE_{ij})\\
=&\;-\left[U^TC(XX^T-C^{-1})CU\right]_{ij}\\
\implies &\; \frac{\partial g(C(F))}{\partial F} =-U^TC(XX^T-C^{-1})CU
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The only problem hereis how to solve this equation to get the optimal $F$ :).

Comment: Well, F = $U^+(XX^T-D){U^+}^T$ sets the derivative to zero (where $U^+ = (U^TU)^{-1}U^T$), but it would take some work to show that it is unique, if it even is. I also can't speak on the convexity of the function by quick inspection.

Comment: If I understand correctly the math the derivative with respect to $D$ will be similar: $diag(C(XX^T-C^{-1})C)=0$. But how did you solve so quickly the equation with respect to $F$?. It is not a linear in $F$.

Comment: I set the inner term, $(XX^T-C^{-1})$, to the zero matrix. Like I said, it may not be unique.

Comment: But with your solution it will not be a zero matrix. It will be of rank n-p matrix orthogonal to $U$. Nevertheless it might be true, I am checking.

Comment: Unfortunalety you solution for $F$ does not seem correct to me. It does not make zero the derivative. What it seems correct for me (I got it from the other perspective) is $F=U^+XX^TU^{+T}$, $D=diag(XX^T-UFU^T)$, but I cannot prove it yet.

Comment: Ah yes, I see where I made the error. You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\C{C^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{trace}\LR{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracBR#1#2{\BR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Calculate the differential of the $C$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
C &= \LR{D+UFU^T}^{-1} \\
dC &= -C\;d\C\,C \\&= -C\LR{U\;dF\;U^T}C \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential of $f,\,$ from which the
gradient wrt $F$ can be extracted
$$\eqalign{
f &= XX^T:C \;-\; \trace{\log(C)} \\
df &= \LR{XX^T-\C}:dC \\
 &= -\LR{XX^T-\C}:\LR{CU\;dF\,U^TC} \\
 &= U^TC\LR{\C-XX^T}CU:dF \\
 &= U^T\!\LR{C-CXX^TC}U:dF \\
\grad{f}{F} &= U^T\!\LR{C-CXX^TC}U \;\doteq\; G \\
}$$
To solve for the optimal $F$, use the gradient $G$ in your favorite gradient descent algorithm.

Mine is *Barzilai-Borwein*, it's simple but very effective.

Initial step
$$\eqalign{
F_0 &= random\;symmetric \\
G_0 &= G(F_0) \\
f_0 &= f(F_0) \\
F_1 &= F_0 - \fracLR{0.05\;\big|f_0\big|}{G_0:G_0} G_0
 \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \\
k &= 1 \\
}$$
Subsequent steps
$$\eqalign{
G_k &= G(F_k) \\
F_{k+1} &= F_k - \fracBR
 {\LR{F_k-F_{k-1}}:\LR{F_k-F_{k-1}}}
 {\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}:\LR{G_k-G_{k-1}}}^{\frac12} G_k \\
k &= k+1 \\
}$$
Stop when $G_k\approx 0$

---

In the above $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
M:\LR{AB} &= \LR{MB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TM}:B \\
}$$
${\sf NB\!:}\;\;C$ and $XX^T$ are symmetric, which simplifies some of the listed properties.